# RouteUrl/javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

For the following code, I'm getting the error "The name fn does not exist in the current context." The error is happening on page load and on the last line of this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function RunAdvancedSearchClicked() {
        var fn = $("#FirstName").val();
        var ln = $("#LastName").val();
        var ssn = $("#SSN").val();
        var doi = $("#DateOfInjury").val();

        document.location = '@Url.RouteUrl("ClaimSearch", new { action = "Search", firstName = fn, lastName = ln, dateOfInjury = doi, carrier = ViewBag.Carrier })';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: You cannot mix server-side code and client-side variables like that.

Comment: @SLaks Ah. What's the best way to build this string, then? I think I've seen a search-and-replace done on special strings before.

Comment: @SLaks You were the first one to get me on track to solve this issue. If you want to give your answer officially, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Url.RouteUrl() is executed when the markup is being rendered (on the server) before the client executes.

You could generate part of the link on the server, then append the value in javascript:

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("ClaimSearch", new { action = "Search", lastName = ln, dateOfInjury = doi, carrier = ViewBag.Carrier })';
document.location = url + '&firstName=' + fn;
```